# Under what conditions is the sum of all the proper divisors an odd number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Under what conditions is σ(n) odd?
σ(n) = the sum of all proper divisors of n

My Answer: I found out that σ(n) is odd iff n is a square number

Is that the only case, or are there more?

Comment: I believe that $\sigma(n)$ is also odd if $n$ is twice a square number, and together with your case, those are the only values of $n$ making $\sigma(n)$ odd.

Comment: Ok got it thanks. How would I go about proving that?

Comment: See my answer. $\space$

Comment: @Frpzzd: Why did you undo my edit? The original question was incorrect (and is now incorrect again).

Comment: @KaushalRaipancholia Why did you unaccept my answer? If you explain, maybe I can fix it.

Comment: @Frpzzd I haven't done anything

Comment: @KaushalRaipancholia Well, for some reason, my answer is no longer accepted (the $\checkmark$ is gone).

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\sigma$ is a multiplicative function. Thus, let us make use of the prime factorization of $n$ and write
$$n=p_1^{m_1}\cdot p_2^{m_2}\cdot...\cdot p_k^{m_k}$$
with distinct primes and nonzero multiplicities. Then we have that
$$\sigma(n)=\sigma(p_1^{m_1})\cdot \sigma(p_2^{m_2})\cdot ...\cdot \sigma(p_k^{m^k})$$
and so $\sigma(n)$ is odd if and only if each $\sigma(p_i^{m_i})$ is odd. Note that
$$\sigma(p_i^{m_i})=1+p_i+p_i^2+...+p_i^{m_i}$$
If $p_i=2$, then this is always odd, so the multiplicity of $2$ in $n$ can be anything. If $p_i\ne 2$, then $p_i$ is odd, and so $\sigma(p_i^{m_i})$ is odd if and only if $m_i$ is even (which can be seen from its expression as a sum written above). Thus, the multiplicity of each prime factor of $n$ must be even with the exception of $2$, meaning that $n$ is in the form $n=k^2$ or $n=2k^2$ with $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: OP is referring to the sum of *proper* divisors and so the function in question is not multiplicative.