# on the equation $\sigma(n+1)=\sigma(n)+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(k)$ denote the sum of all positive divisors of $k$.

Consider the equation $\sigma(n+1)=\sigma(n)+1$.

Has it been investigated before? (I did some search in books avaliable for me, and in the internet, didn't found)

Does it have a solution except $n=2$ ?

I checked up to $10^7$, there are no other solutions in this interval.

Comment: For this to be true, one of $\sigma(n),\sigma(n+1)$ must be odd.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978422/under-what-conditions-is-the-sum-of-all-the-proper-divisors-an-odd-number) shows that this is so only if $n$ is a square or twice a square.  That sounds like a good starting point.  (At least, it makes computer search mush more efficient.)

Comment: The closest thing I know of is a result of Heath-Brown, which states that the equation $d(n)=d(n+1)$ has infinitely many solutions, where $d$ counts the number of divisors. Presumably, one might be able to adapt that method to the equation $\sigma(n) = \sigma(n+1)$. Unfortunately, I don't think the method would apply to this problem.

Comment: As a side note, if the twin prime conjecture is true, then the equation $\sigma(n+2)=\sigma(n)+2$ has infinitely many solutions, since any prime $p$ with $p+2$ also prime would be a solution.

Comment: Applying saulspatz's hint, I currently run a search for $n\le 10^{14}$. The only pairs I found so far with difference $1$ are $(2/3)$ (which is the solution mentioned in the question) and $(4/5)$ which is no solution because of $\sigma(4)>\sigma(5)$.

Comment: Finished. No more pairs found. This leads to a stronger conjecture.

Comment: @Peter What stronger conjecture does your last comment lead to? Or did you just mean your search "strengthens" in the sense of checking for much larger numbers?

Comment: @coffeemath The stronger conjecture is that the only pairs $(n/n+1)$ with $$|\sigma(n)-\sigma(n+1)|=1$$ are $(2/3)$ and $(4/5)$